# Как сделать значение названием колонки?

Tags: sql, pivot

У меня есть таблица:

```
market | region | open_time
pyat     msk      09:00
pyat     kiev     10:00
mag      msk      22:00
...
```

и нужно получить следующее

```
market | msk | kiev
pyat    09:00  10:00
mag     22:00  null
```

Основная проблема заключается в том, что при `SELECT open_time as region` присваивается названию колонки слово `region` а не само значение (название региона).

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)#:~:text=COLUMN%20ALIASES%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0).

Comment: из вопроса непонятна цель, что именно требуется получить. алиасы проставляют название поля при выборке.

Comment: "Как сделать значение названием колонки" каким образом название колонки может быть одно для множества строк?)

Comment: Это PIVOT. Вид запроса и вообще наличие поддержки зависит от конкретной СУБД и её версии. Общего решения - не существует, PIVOT нереляционен.

Comment: Добавьте метку конкретной СУБД в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте с `PIVOT` клаузой ([см. pivot_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)):

```
with t ("market", "region", "open_time") as (
    select 'pyat', 'msk',  '09:00' from dual union all
    select 'pyat', 'kiev', '10:00' from dual union all
    select 'mag',  'msk',  '22:00' from dual)
-- отсюда начинается сам запрос, выше тестовые данные    
select * 
from t
pivot (max ("open_time") for "region" in ('msk' as "msk", 'kiev' as "kiev"))
/
```

Результат:

```
mark msk   kiev 
---- ----- -----
pyat 09:00 10:00
mag  22:00 null
```

Answer (score 2):

На любом брэнде БД должен работать такой запрос:

```
select 
    market as "market", 
    max(case region when 'msk'  then open_time end) as "msk",
    max(case region when 'kiev' then open_time end) as "kiev"
from t
group by market 
order by market desc
```

Проверить можно на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=85223e507dd397255fe5d8a714631080). Для *SQLite* дало такой результат:

```
market  msk     kiev
------  -----   -----
pyat    09:00   10:00
mag     22:00   null
```